# How to use string values in a data.frame as indexes to use in a matrix?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, matrix

I have an R dataframe like this,

```
tttt<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("5,4","1,2"),c("2,1","2,2")))
```

Then, I want to use the values in that dataframe as index to call values in a matrix like this,

```
mymatrix[tttt[1,1]]
```

However, if I use this previous line of code doesn't work because the values in tttt are strings. I have tried noquote(tttt[1,1]), cat(tttt[1,1]), print(tttt[1,1]) or factor(tttt[1,1]) but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

We may split at the `,`, by reading, convert it to two column matrix and use that as index

```
mymatrix[as.matrix(read.csv(text = unlist(tttt), header = FALSE))]
```

We `unlist` the `data.frame` first to create a vector though

```
as.matrix(read.csv(text = unlist(tttt), header = FALSE))
     V1 V2
[1,]  5  4
[2,]  1  2
[3,]  2  1
[4,]  2  2
```